# Resizing colorbox with previuos and next button with iframe

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am using colorbox iframe.

```
$('.preview-popup').colorbox({
        rel: 'preview-popup',
        width: width,
        height: height,
        iframe: true,
        scrolling: false});
```

displaying images inside colorbox.

How can I resize the colobox  automatically with the height and width of the images with clicking prev and next button ?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are setting width and height to the colorbox....by default it uses images' height and width only

[colorbox documentation](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

Comment: I am rendering images from another response in the iframe, so it could not get the image reference directly on the link.